# Create an array of value contained in objects in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'd like to select it to have an array of only objects values
My array:

```
  favorites: [{ idSave: '10000', isChecked: true },
  { idSave: '10001', isChecked: true },
  { idSave: '18807', isChecked: true }]
```

The expected output:

```
['10000','10001','18807']
```

My code:

```
let favorites = req.user.favorites
        favorites.forEach((arrayItem) => {
            let idSaveMain = arrayItem.idSave
            let idSaveArr = [ idSaveMain]
            console.log(idSaveArr)
        })
```

The actual output:

```
['10000']
['10001']
['18807']
```

Comment: `[ idSaveMain]` is creating a new array. You want to only create it once and then add to it. Create it outside the loop and use `push` to add to it.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` is all you need.

Comment: `const out = req.user.favorites.map(({idSave}) => idSave);`